# UIPickerView that worked in iOS 6.1 now crashes in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I developed an app for iOS 6 that called a UIPickerView. Now that I upgraded to Xcode 5, the app works fine for iOS 7, but no longer for iOS 6.

The app crashes when it segues to the pickerview.The pickerview has 1 component and 10 rows.

The header file is below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface DxChooserViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *ptDxPicker;

- (IBAction)dismissDxChooser:(id)sender;

@end
```

And pertinent sections of the implementation:

```
#import "DxChooserViewController.h"

...

@implementation DxChooserViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad    
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _dxNames=@[@"NILM (Negative Pap)",@"ASC-US",@"LSIL",@"ASC-H",@"HSIL",@"AGC",@"Atypical Endometrial Cells",@"Atypical Endocervical Cells",@"AIS (adenocarcinoma in situ)",@"Unsatisfactory Pap"];

    NSString *chosenDxString = ((ViewController *)self.presentingViewController).ptDx.text;
    int chosenDxInt = 0;
    if ([chosenDxString isEqualToString:@""]) {
        chosenDxInt = 0;
    } else {
        chosenDxInt = [_dxNames indexOfObject:(chosenDxString)];
    }

    [self.ptDxPicker selectRow:(NSInteger)chosenDxInt inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    ViewController *initialView;
    initialView = (ViewController *)self.delegate;

    NSString *chosenDxString = ((ViewController *)self.presentingViewController).ptDx.text;
    int chosenDxInt = 0;
    if ([chosenDxString isEqualToString:@""]) {
        chosenDxInt = 0;
    } else {
        chosenDxInt = [_dxNames indexOfObject:(chosenDxString)];
    }

    [initialView displayDx:_dxNames[(NSInteger)chosenDxInt]]; // returns default dx if nothing is selected
}

...

@end
```

---

Update:

The problem was solved, but here is what the crash was:

> 2013-12-14 10:47:54.518 Pap Reader[48513:907] * * * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '* * * -[NSMutableIndexSet addIndexesInRange:]: Range {2147483647, 1} exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1'

Comment: Sorry I forgot to do that. The problem was solved, but here is what the crash was:

2013-12-14 10:47:54.518 Pap Reader[48513:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableIndexSet addIndexesInRange:]: Range {2147483647, 1} exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1'

Answer (score 1):

One possible source of crash is if the desired `chosenDxString` was not successfully found in the array (i.e. you should check to make sure that `chosenDxInt` did not return `NSNotFound`). You also don't check to make sure that `chosenDxString` was not `nil`.

Thus, you might replace:

```
int chosenDxInt = 0;
if ([chosenDxString isEqualToString:@""]) {
    chosenDxInt = 0;
} else {
    chosenDxInt = [_dxNames indexOfObject:(chosenDxString)];
}
```

with:

```
int chosenDxInt = 0;
if (choseDxString && ![chosenDxString isEqualToString:@""]) {
    chosenDxInt = [_dxNames indexOfObject:chosenDxString];
    if (chosenDxInt == NSNotFound)
        chosenDxInt = 0;
}
```

You also have a programmatically defined array of values, but you're not showing us the code that specifies the delegate/datasource of the picker view and retrieves those values. So I presume you've set the datasource/delegate properties of the picker view and have implemented methods like:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.dxNames count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.dxNames[row];
}
```

In terms of the specific problem in your case, you must update your question with the details of the crash (the details of the crash, at what line it crashed). If it's not apparent which line you're crashing at (i.e. it's just cryptically referring to your `main` function), you might also want to turn on [exception breakpoints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) so it highlights the offending line of code when it crashes.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your response solved the problem, although I had forgotten to provide you with details about the crash. Your response reminded me that I had forgotten that I need to check for the possibility of chosenDxString being nil, not just @"". I added that condition and it worked!

Comment: @user3102735 Yep, that error message that you provided is telling you that `indexOfObject` returned `NSNotFound`. Glad you solved the problem!